# literally started learning coding from free sources and already ran into issues at beginner level at python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

i was practising beginner level programming, and i came up with a question stated, 'price of a house is 1 million. if buyer has good credit, they need to put down 10%. otherwise they need to put down 20%.' now, the main question is 'print down the statement'. therefore, i started with a fairly complex code(i know there are much better and simpler ways to solve this, but i would be very grateful if someone could help me solve it with the respective program).  my respective code:

```
price = '$1000000'

good_credit = (10/100*float(price))
bad_credit = (20/100*float(price))

lit_credit = print(round(good_credit))
unsatisfactory_credit = print(round(bad_credit))

awesome_credit = price - lit_credit 
poor_credit = price - unsatisfactory_credit

awesome_credit = True
poor_credit = False

if awesome_credit:
  print(price - good_credit)
elif poor_credit:
  print(price - bad_credit)
```

when i run this program, the error states cannot convert string to float. anyways, can someone please help me out for the sake of my curiosity and to help me visualize where my mistake was(i would appreciate if the updated program you send is a working one and if it meets all demands of the question) . i would really appreciate it if someone could help.
i have tried to make it run the code by making it much simpler by only including good_credit and bad_credit variables, but it just does not seem to work that simply. however, i now want to learn how i can run the code with the variables i am using and i would be grateful if someone can kindly answer why my code cannot convert string to float; or is it just not possible.

thank you very much!

Comment: `price = '$1000000'` you're assigning a string to the `price` variable. Try doing `price = 1000000`

Comment: why do you have a `print` statement assignment in these two statements? `lit_credit = print(round(good_credit))` and `unsatisfactory_credit = print(round(bad_credit))` Note that `print (anything)` will result in `None` assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert a string to a float, but you have the `$` sign so you need to remove it.

```
good_credit = (10/100*float(price))
bad_credit = (20/100*float(price))
```

Next you're going to get an error saying this `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '$1000000'`, this basically means it can't convert the `$` sign at the beginning of the string. A simple fix is to simply remove the `$` sign. The next error you're going to get is `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'NoneType'`, this is because you're trying to subtract `None` from a string, `lit_credit` and `unsatisfactory_credit` are being assigned `None` because you assigned them the return value of `print()`. A simple fix to this is to remove the `print()` and add it in after you assigned your variables.

```
lit_credit = round(good_credit)
unsatisfactory_credit = round(bad_credit)
print(lit_credit, unsatisfactory_credit)
```

The Next error you're going to run into is this `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'`. This basically means you can't subtract a string(`price`) from an integer(`lit_credit` and `unsatisfactory_credit`). A fix to this would be to turn `price` into an integer like this. Also I have no idea what the point of this code was or what it does relating to your question but this is what it should look like for whatever reason you put it here.

```
awesome_credit = int(price) - lit_credit
poor_credit = int(price) - unsatisfactory_credit
```

Now this next block of code makes no sense

```
awesome_credit = True
poor_credit = False

if awesome_credit:
  print(int(price) - good_credit)
elif poor_credit:
  print(int(price) - bad_credit)
```

If what you're trying to do is ask the user whether they have good or bad credit then figure out the down payment they need to make, you'd need to ask for an input using the `input()` function.

Comment: A `str` converts directly to `float` just fine; the `$` makes it invalid for both `int` and `float`; removing it would allow direct conversion to `float`, no need for `int` intermediate.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, no you cannot convert $1000000 to float because while converting, your machine will not understand what $ is and so it will give an error that it can't convert to float.But if you gave only 1000000 without the symbol then, it would be able to convert it.

Next, your code will give you an error because in these lines:

awesome_credit = price - lit_credit

poor_credit = price - unsatisfactory_credit

You have not defined lit_credit or unsatisfactory_credit as an integer, rather you have printed them, so in your code, remove the print statement while you assign to these variables.

And finally if awesome_credit is always going to be True, then your code is right, but if you want to actually check whether awesome_credit will be True, you have to ask for an input and then use an if..else block.(Just a suggestion)

Answer (score 1):

```
price = 1000000

scores = {"good_credit":(10/100* price),"bad_credit":(20/100* price )}

awesome_credit = price - scores["good_credit"]
poor_credit = price - scores["bad_credit"]

if awesome_credit:
  print(f'Good Credit Final Price: ${price - scores["good_credit"]}')
elif poor_credit:
  print(f'Poor Credit Final Price: ${price - scores["bad_credit"]}')
```

Personally this is how I would do it, you can't convert a string to a float, in your first variable declaration you have price = "1000000" , any value between double quotes or single quotes is a string, you don't actually need to force it to be a float at all, math preformed on numbers is allowed. You also don't need to round the credit values unless you wanted to.

There is one major flaw in your code and even in the code I sent over, There is no reason to define awesome_credit and poor_credit as true or false, in fact your overwriting the value. The issue is also that because they have values both of them are true. It will always be good credit. Now to fix this, you need to determine what defines good credit or bad credit. In the real world you would be dealing with 2 situations, 1) you are working with something like django and the credit scores would be fetched from a model, or 2) where you are calculating a value for good or bad credit and you have a baseline , above is good below is bad.

Hoped this helped cheers!

Comment: I forgot to add this link, but I published this answer on my github https://github.com/SN3-K/SO-answer-1

Answer (score 0):

Just need to parse the price, remove the $ sign and remove the print() statement around your credit assigned variables :)

```
#Parse to float and remove the $ symbol
price = float('1000000')

good_credit = (10/100*float(price))
bad_credit = (20/100*float(price))

#Remove Print Statements in these 2 lines
lit_credit = round(good_credit)
unsatisfactory_credit = round(bad_credit)

#These should work now
#Error was coming from attempting to mathemtically substract a print statement (lit and unsatisfactory credit) from a string (price)
awesome_credit = price - lit_credit 
poor_credit = price - unsatisfactory_credit

awesome_credit = True
poor_credit = False

if awesome_credit:
  print(price - good_credit)
elif poor_credit:
  print(price - bad_credit)
```